Sorting an array/list by a specific item in an array attribute
I'm new to python/jmespath and am trying to sort the below students by their final grade in 2024. I'm sure I can come up with something in python to do it but was just wondering if there is any jmespath magic I can use. I have seen sort_by and know how to search/sort by simple attributes, but haven't yet found anything that can do this.
{
    "school": "lame",
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Joe", 
            "grades": [
                {"year": 2024, "final": 85}, 
                {"year": 2023, "final": 73}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Pedro", 
            "grades": [
                {"year": 2024, "final": 92}, 
                {"year": 2023, "final": 90}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "name": "Mary", 
            "grades": [
                {"year": 2024, "final": 88}, 
                {"year": 2023, "final": 70}
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Don't use jmespath if you're concerned about runtime performance. Comparing Python with the jmespath solutions proposed here reveals the latter to be incredibly slow

@SIGHUP Is there a cheat sheet somewhere on when to use and when not to use jmespath?

I doubt it very much

Assuming that you want to sort by the latest year (not specifically the value 2024), you could achieve it with this:
jmespath.search("students | sort_by(@,&grades|max_by(@,&year).final)", data)

That would result in:
[{'id': 1,
  'name': 'Joe',
  'grades': [{'year': 2024, 'final': 85}, {'year': 2023, 'final': 73}]},
 {'id': 3,
  'name': 'Mary',
  'grades': [{'year': 2024, 'final': 88}, {'year': 2023, 'final': 70}]},
 {'id': 2,
  'name': 'Pedro',
  'grades': [{'year': 2024, 'final': 92}, {'year': 2023, 'final': 90}]}]


If you actually wanted to sort by the year 2024 specifically, you could use this:
jmespath.search("students | sort_by(@,&(grades[?year==`2024`].final)[0])", data)

But you would gen an error if you have any student record without any grade in 2024, as the index selector [0] would return null.
In that case you have two options:

If you want to ignore students without 2024 grade, you could use this:
jmespath.search("students[?grades[?year==`2024`]] | sort_by(@,&(grades[?year==`2024`].final)[0])", data)


If you want to sort them at the end or beginning:
jmespath.search("students | sort_by(@,&(grades[?year==`2024`].final)[0]||`0`)", data)
jmespath.search("students | sort_by(@,&(grades[?year==`2024`].final)[0]||`999`)", data)




It should be noted that this technique does not alter the data in situ. Of course, that may or may not be a requirement

that is most commonly the case with jmespath

Here is a JMESPath solution:
sort_by(students, &(grades[?year == `2024`].final)[0])

(it took me some trial and error to find that the parentheses around grades[?year == `2024`].final part were necessary)
So for each student it filters their grades to just the year 2024, takes the final field from each remaining grade resulting in a single element list, then takes the first item from that list and uses it as the sort key.
I'm not sure what happens if any student is missing a grade for the filtered year - I guess they will either get sorted first or last.
I've only tried this via the online version on their homepage https://jmespath.org/

I have no doubt that jmespath has its place but in this particular case it's remarkably inefficient when compared to list.sort

If a student record is missing a grade for the year, it throws an exception. See this answer for more details.
